# In which cases can the `:title` property of a headline, returned by `org-element` not be a string? (Or how to get the title string reliably?)

Tags: parsing, emacs, org-mode

I am trying to parse an org file with `org-element`.

```
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline) 'headline
      (lambda (a-hl)
        (message "debug:title:%s" (org-element-property :title a-hl)))
```

The code above works. However, the code below, which is just a little bit different, does not work the way I expect it to work:

```
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
      (lambda (a-hl)
        (message "debug:title:%s" (org-element-property :title a-hl)))
```

Istead of the result being identical, it is printing giant trees of sexps, although seemingly the difference should be in speed only.

What can I do to get the title reliably?

hraban added a better reproducible example:

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (org-mode)
  (insert "* Hello")
  (cl-flet ((say-type (prefix hl)
              (message "Headline title from %s is of type: %s"
                       prefix
                       (type-of (org-element-property :title hl)))))
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
      (lambda (hl) (say-type "map" hl)))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (say-type "context" (org-element-context))
    (say-type "at-point" (org-element-at-point))))
```

Expected result: strings everywhere. Actual result:

```
Headline title from map is of type: cons
Headline title from context is of type: string
Headline title from at-point is of type: string
```

Comment: do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Is the list of headlines really different in the two cases? AFAICT, the two lists should have the same length and the same list of names (although in the first case you might get `"foo"` for an element of the list, whereas in the second it might be `("foo")` instead (that's what I see although I have not investigated in detail). But there should be an obvious 1-1 mapping between the two.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! When I use `(org-element-context)`, the headline's `:title` is just a string. But when I use `(org-element-parse-buffer)` and map over that, its title is basically a 1-element list containing a string with properties. I don't mind the properties (still a string after all), but the weird single-element-list wrapping makes it hard to work with reliably.

Comment: I asked on the mailing list and got a good answer from Ihor Radchenko.

Answer (score 0):

Ihor Radchenko has [the answer](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2023-08/msg00601.html):

```
(org-element-interpret-data ...)
```

> This is "anonymous element". `org-element-parse-buffer', by default,
> parses down to object level:
>
> ```
> * Heading *bold* text
> ```
>
> contains bold markup, which is reflected in the parsed AST. The title
> itself is called secondary value, which may contain Org markup.
>
> You are not getting it using `org-element-at-point' API because it does
> not parse objects and simply returns a heading parsed down to element
> level - :title is not parsed in details.

### Fix using Ihor's recommendation

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (org-mode)
  (insert "* Hello")
  (cl-flet ((say-type (prefix hl)
              (message "Headline title from %s is: %s"
                       prefix
                       (org-element-interpret-data (org-element-property :title hl)))))
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
      (lambda (hl) (say-type "map" hl)))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (say-type "context" (org-element-context))
    (say-type "at-point" (org-element-at-point))))
```